# AngularJS in SharePoint 2013 on a closed network

Tags: 2013, javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have built a few sample web pages with AngularJS and uploading them to my SharePoint 2013 library, referencing angular.min.js. Now I am working on a closed network with no access to the Internet, and my sample web pages are not working. I copied the latest version of angular.min.js (1.6.4) to this network and tried it in Site Assets as well as in the same library as my pages, but the Angular code does not work.

I have successfully used jquery samples with the jquery library in the same locations, and they work fine. Is there some other library besides angular.min.js that I need to upload? Do I need the non-minimized version of angular?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, my IE11 was setting document mode to 5. I added the following line in the head tag and it fixed the problem:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
```

More discussion where I posted this question on Stack Overflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45663637/angular-on-a-closed-network